# Trouble calculating slope and intercept in Numpy/Scypy using linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

i'm new in this forum.
I have a small problem to understand how to calcolate slope and intercept from value that are in a csv file.

This is my working codes(minquadbasso.py is the programme's name):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To visualize
import pandas as pd  # To read data
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pd.read_csv('TelefonoverticaleAsseY.csv')  # load data set
X = data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # values converts it into a numpy array
Y = data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # -1 means that calculate the dimension of rows, but have 1 column

linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X) # make predictions

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='black')
plt.show()
```

If I use:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
linregress(X, Y)
```

compiler give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minquadbasso.py", line 11, in <module>
    linregress(X, Y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py", line 116, in linregress
    ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Can you make me understand what i'm doing wrong and suggest what change in order to calculate seccesfully slope and intercept?

Comment: The result of `ndarray.flat` is an iterator to the data i.e. just a single object. I suggest you either just use the returned array as a whole (i.e. without the `flat`), which gives you a single numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

My go-to for linear regression is np.polyfit. If you have an array (or list) of x data, and an array or list of y data just use

```
coeff = np.polyfit(x,y, deg = 1)
```

coeff is now a list of least square coefficients to fit your data, with highest degree of x first. So for a first degree fit y = ax + b, 
`a = coeff[0]` and `b = coeff[1]` 'deg' is the degree of the polynomial you want to fit to your data. To evaluate your regression (predict) you can use np.polyval

```
y_prediction = np.polyval(coeff, x)
```

If you want the covariance matrix for the fit

```
coeff, cov = np.polyfit(x,y, deg = 1, cov = True)
```

you can find more on it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).